# My ASP.NET REST app is returning JSON even though the client is requesting XML

Tags: asp.net-web-api, xml-serialization

I have an ASP.NET Web API2 web application. For its configuration it has:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.XmlFormatter.UseXmlSerializer = true;
```

The client is requesting XML:

```
private static HttpWebRequest CreatetRequest(Uri uri, string method, int timeout)
{
    var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
    request.Method = method;
    request.Timeout = timeout == 0 ? System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite : timeout;
    request.Accept = "application/xml";
    request.ContentType = "application/xml";
    return request;
}
```

But what is being returned is JSON. And when the client then makes the following call:

```
       using (var stream = response.GetResponseStream())
        {
                body = XDocument.Load(XmlReader.Create(stream));
```

It throws an exception because it can't load JSON as XML. What do I need to do on the server side to fix this (I can't change the client side - that code is out and in use)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it - one of the objects being returned dd not have a parameterless constructor. XML serialization requires that while JSON does not.